# Load resources with variables?

Tags: android, android-resources

I am loading XML file resource like this,

```
getResources().getXml(R.xml.fiel1);
```

Now, the scenario is that depending on factors there may be many xml files to choose from. How do I do that? 
In this case the filename is similar in the fact that all starts with file only ends with different numbers like 
file1, file2,file3 etc., So I can just form a String variable with the file name and add a suffix as per requirement to form a filename like  file1 (file+1).
Problem is I keep getting various errors (NullPointerEx, ResourceId Not found etc) in whatever way I try to pass the filename variable to the method. 
What is the correct way of accomplishing this?

Comment: You probably need to use reflection to get the corresponding id based on the name and pass the id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) but the docs mention:

> use of this function is discouraged.
>   It is much more efficient to retrieve
>   resources by identifier than by name.

So it's better to use an array which references the xml files. You can declare it as an [integer array resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#IntegerArray). Eg, in `res/values/arrays.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer-array name="xml_files">
        <item>@xml/file1</item>
        <item>@xml/file2</item>
        etc...
    </integer-array>
</resources>
```

And then in Java:

```
private XmlResourceParser getXmlByIndex(int index) {
    Resources res = getResources();
    return res.getXml(res.getIntArray(R.array.xml_files)[index - 1]);
}
```

Of course, you'll need to update the array whenever you add a new xml file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method of Resources to find the id.

```
Resources res = getResources();
for(/* loop */) {
    int id = res.getIdentifier("file" + i, "xml", "my.package.name");
    res.getXml(id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the `getIdentifier` suggestions, assuming the number of resources is fixed at compile time, would be to create a static mapping between an identifier and the resource.

So for example you could use the suffixed numerical ID:

```
class Whatever {
    static final int[] resources = new int[] {
        R.xml.file1, R.xml.file2, R.xml.file3
    }
}
```

This would allow you retrieve the resource with a simple index operation.

```
getResources().getXml(resources[i]);
```

Alternatively, if you needed a more descriptive mapping you can use any one of java's [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)-based classes.

```
class Whatever {
    static final Map<String, Integer> resources = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    static {
        resources.put("file1", R.xml.file1);
        resources.put("file2", R.xml.file2);
        resources.put("file3", R.xml.file3);
        resources.put("something_else", R.xml.something_else);
    }
}
```

With this you would then `get(String)` the value by its name.