# How to use RAW folder for multiple audio files

Tags: java, android, audio

I have the following function:

```
strNameValue = prefs.getString("NamePosition", "");
        inNameValueConversion = Integer.parseInt(strNameValue);

        if (inNameValueConversion == 0) {
            DisplayInformation(inNameValueConversion, R.raw.audio01);
        }
        if (inNameValueConversion == 1) {
            DisplayInformation(inNameValueConversion, R.raw.audio02);
        }
        if (inNameValueConversion == 2) {
            DisplayInformation(inNameValueConversion, R.raw.audio03);
        }
        if (inNameValueConversion == 3) {
            DisplayInformation(inNameValueConversion, R.raw.audio04);
        }
```

Because all the audio file starts with `audio` and only the number changes at the end I wanted to create a function which allows me to use less code like this:

```
public void DisplayInformation(int inNum, final int inSoundResource) {
        if (inSoundResource < 2) {
            strIConv = String.valueOf("0" + inSoundResource);
            inConv = Integer.parseInt(strIConv);
            int k = R.raw.audio+"inConv";
        }
}
```

I get the following error: `audio cannot be resolved or is not a field`

How do I edit the above code so I can just use one function instead of using so many IF statement, since it will be 90+ times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use getIdentifier(), so your code would look like this:

```
public void displayInformation(int inNum) {
    String id = "audio"; 

    // for inNum < 9, we need to add 0, so for example when you pass 0
    // id will be 01, not 1
    if (inNum < 9) then id += "0";

    //based on your code, 0 - audio01, 1 - audio02 etc, so add 1
    id += (inNum + 1); 

    // call getIdentifier with string containing resource name, which are in your raw folder
    // and in your package
    int k = getResources().getIdentifier(id, "raw", "your.package.name.here");

    //k now contains an id of your resource, so do whatever you want with it
}
```

and your code can then be reduced to this:

```
strNameValue = prefs.getString("NamePosition", "");
inNameValueConversion = Integer.parseInt(strNameValue);

displayInformation(inNameValueConversion);
```

Remember to use your package name in the call to getIdentifier().

Docs are here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: I actually was looking through my old code and found it and its exactly what you posted. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do it like it is mentioned in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5626631/3178834

In your case, you have to create an array for all audio files as resources xml and then load it with `res.getXml` into java. Just follow the link from above.

Answer (score 1):

Building R values that way won't work -- you'll need to use reflection instead.

For example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
/* ... */


int id = R.id.class.getField("video" + i).getInt(0);
```